# Play streaming video using ASP.NET web application

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I am developing a Document sharing web application. I want to stream the videos (most commonly used formats are MPEG and AVI, just like YouTube.com.

Which control should i use to play videos? The user will upload video files and then other users can view them.

I can use Jquery, or pure server side control for this. Please suggest.

Also how can i one view PowerPoint files or other Microsoft Office file formats online, just like slideshare.net.

Comment: HTML5 video element is an option if you don't require support for the older browsers. See http://caniuse.com/#search=video

Answer (score 2):

Just use the HTML5 `<video src="<%= pathToVideoFile %>" />` element. Browsers will render it fine by themselves. If the video is stored in a web-accessible filesystem location just link directly to it, otherwise if it exists in a database then you should implement an `*.ashx` handler that simply returns the data from the database directly in the response (with the correct MIME-type, of course).

It goes without saying that your videos must be encoded correctly. If they're H.264 then you'll be fine. You'll run into problems if they're DivX or MPEG-2 (as Windows 8 no-longer comes with an MPEG-2 decoder by default). I suggest you convert all uploaded videos into H.264 when they're added to your system. You can do this with `ffmpeg`.

If you're targeting previous-generation browsers (IE8 basically) then you'll need to use a Flash SWF video player. A good popular one is [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players), another (free) one is [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/). This is all done client-side by adding a few `<script>` blocks to your site.

Making PowerPoint files visible over the Internet is an exercise is pain. Do not attempt. There are companies that spend lots of money building entire websites devoted to that single task and fail miserably.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it comes with a non-html 5 fallback if I read correctly http://lifehacker.com/5536050/embed-html5-videos-with-multi+browser-support-on-your-site

Here's another html5/ non html 5 method worth looking into http://blogfreakz.com/video/cross-browser-video-player/

The direct link http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody